# CUDA 5.0 namespaces for constant memory variable usage

Tags: cuda, namespaces

In my program I want to use a structure containing constant variables and keep it on device all long as the program executes to completion.

I have several header files containing the declaration of '**global**' functions and their respective '.cu' files for their definitions. I kept this scheme because it helps me contain similar code in one place. e.g. all the '**device**' functions required to complete '**KERNEL_1**' are separated from those '**device**' functions required to complete '**KERNEL_2**' along with kernels definitions.

I had no problems with this scheme during compilation and linking. Until I encountered constant variables. I want to use the same constant variable through all kernels and device functions but it doesn't seem to work.

```
##########################################################################
                                CODE EXAMPLE
###########################################################################
filename: 'common.h'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct {
    double height;
    double weight;
    int age;
} __CONSTANTS;

__constant__ __CONSTANTS d_const;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
filename: main.cu
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "common.h"
#include "gpukernels.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    __CONSTANTS T;
    T.height   = 1.79;
    T.weight   = 73.2;
    T.age      = 26;

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_const, &T, sizeof(__CONSTANTS));
    test_kernel <<< 1, 16 >>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
filename: gpukernels.h
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__global__ void test_kernel();

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
filename: gpukernels.cu
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include "gpukernels.h"
#include "common.h"

__global__ void test_kernel() {
    printf("Id: %d, height: %f, weight: %f\n", threadIdx.x, d_const.height, d_const.weight);
}
```

When I execute this code, the kernel executes, displays the thread ids, but the constant values are displayed as zeros. How can I fix this?

### MODIFICATIONS AS SUGGESTED

```
filename: gpukernels.h
----------------------------------------------------------------------

__global__ void test_kernel();

----------------------------------------------------------------------
filename: gpukernels.cu
----------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"
#include "gpukernels.h"

extern "C" __constant__ __CONSTANTS d_const;

__global__ void test_kernel() {
    printf("Id: %d, Height: %f, Weight: %f\n", threadIdx.x, d_const.height, d_const.weight);
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
filename: common.h
----------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct {
    double height;
    double weight;
    int age;
} __CONSTANTS;

----------------------------------------------------------------------
filename: main.cu
----------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "common.h"
#include "gpukernels.h"

__constant__ __CONSTANTS d_const;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    __CONSTANTS T;
    T.height = 1.79;
    T.weight = 73.2;
    T.age    = 26;

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_const, &T, sizeof(__CONSTANTS));
    test_kernel <<< 1, 16 >>> ();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

So as suggested, I tried the code, still doesn't work. Did I miss something here?

Comment: I have tested your code by including the `__global__` function in the same file as for the `main` function and it works, provided that you change the misprinted `d_consts` in the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` to `d_const`.

Comment: `__constant__` symbols are implicitly static. Since in your case you are using separate compilation, the constant symbol should be then declared as `extern` in every compilation unit (`gpukernels.cu` in your case) except the one containing the definition (`main.cu` in your case).

Comment: @JackOLantern but Jack in that case I have to write all the code back in the main.cu. which I want to avoid. In my code instead of gpukernels.h I have files such as calculatepdf.h, calculatecdf.h and their respective '.cu' file. I want the constant variable to be accessible to all my kernels in these files as well.

Comment: @JackOLantern so for every other kernel header i need to define it again as `extern`

Comment: I have posted an answer, see below. I think your second version is ok, but perhaps you forgot to generate a relocatable code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, I report the solution which is working for me. Remember that you are using separate compilation, so do not forget to use Generate Relocatable Device Code (`-rdc=true` option).

**FILE main.cu**

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

typedef struct {
    double height;
    double weight;
    int age;
} __CONSTANTS;

__constant__ __CONSTANTS d_const;

__global__ void test_kernel();

#include <conio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    __CONSTANTS T;
    T.height   = 1.79;
    T.weight   = 73.2;
    T.age      = 26;

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_const, &T, sizeof(__CONSTANTS));
    test_kernel <<< 1, 16 >>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**FILE kernel.cu**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

typedef struct {
    double height;
    double weight;
    int age;
} __CONSTANTS;

extern __constant__ __CONSTANTS d_const;

__global__ void test_kernel() {
    printf("Id: %d, height: %f, weight: %f\n", threadIdx.x, d_const.height, d_const.weight);
}
```