# Kernel accessing __constant__ variable from different translation unit

Tags: cuda, linker, constants

I have three files:

Main.cu

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "kernels.cuh"

__constant__ float deviceConstVar;

void setConstantValue(float value) {
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(deviceConstVar, &value, sizeof(float));
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}


int main() {
    setConstantValue(1.23f);

    printConstantValue << <1, 1 >> > ();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

kernels.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

extern __constant__ float deviceConstVar;

__global__ void printConstantValue() {
    printf("deviceConstVar = %f\n", deviceConstVar);
}
```

kernels.cuh

```
// constants.h
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

#include "cuda_runtime.h"

__global__ void printConstantValue();

#endif // CONSTANTS_H
```

The kernel prints 0.000, but not 1.23 as expected.

It seems that the `__constant__` par does not transfer to the kernel.

---

I used visual to build and the commands seems to be:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CudaRuntime1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Compiling CUDA source file kernels.cu...
1>Compiling CUDA source file main.cu...
1>
1>C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0   --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/Fdx64\Debug\vc143.pdb" -o C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1\x64\Debug\main.cu.obj "C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1\main.cu"
1>
1>C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0   --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/Fdx64\Debug\vc143.pdb" -o C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1\x64\Debug\kernels.cu.obj "C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1\kernels.cu"
1>C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1\kernels.cu(4): warning #20044-D: extern declaration of the entity deviceConstVar is treated as a static definition
1>
1>main.cu
1>kernels.cu
1>Done building project "CudaRuntime1.vcxproj".
1>   Creating library C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1\x64\Debug\CudaRuntime1.lib and object C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1\x64\Debug\CudaRuntime1.exp
1>CudaRuntime1.vcxproj -> C:\ShaloTide\CudaRuntime1\x64\Debug\CudaRuntime1.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Rebuild started at 8:33 PM and took 02.316 seconds ==========
```

This is copied from visual studio

Comment: How does your compiler command look like? I would guess that you need to activate device linking.

Comment: Your setConstantValue looks broken to me

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I have added the output of visual studio, which seems to be the compiler command you mentioned.

Comment: the function setConstantValue runs well in visual studio... @talonmies

Comment: you'll need to select device linking.  The need for this is covered in other `cuda` SO posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586545/cuda-5-0-namespaces-for-constant-memory-variable-usage), and how to do it in visual studio is covered in other `cuda` SO posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374736/nvlink-error-undefined-reference-to-in-debug-cu-obj-cuda-separate-compi/54411519#54411519).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @paleonix. The code itself has no issues. The problem lies in the necessity to activate device linking during the build process. In Visual Studio, within the Solution Explorer on the right-hand side, select all the .cu files, then right-click, navigate to Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Common -> Generate Relocatable Device Code, and change it from "No" to "-rdc=true". This should resolve the issue.